# NMDS ordination with both environmental data and species data

Tags: r, vegan

I'm curious if this is possible.
I have the following data:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
dune.spec<-data.frame(Species=colnames(dune))
dune.spec$var1<-runif(30, min=0, max=10)
dune.spec$var2<-runif(30, min=30, max=100)
dune.spec$var3<-runif(30, min=100, max=200)
```

used to create an NMDS and fit the environmental dataset dune.env

```
ord <- metaMDS(dune)
ord.fit <- envfit(ord ~ A1 + Management, data=dune.env, perm=999)
plot(ord, dis="species")
plot(ord.fit)
```

However, I have further data about the species I would also like to fit:

```
View(dune.spec)
```

Can this be done?

edited for (hopefully) clarity:
I don't want to fit spec.env to site scores. site scores are in dune.env. I am wondering if there is a meaningful way to add both measures to an NMDS. So for example I would have sites, with scores for environmental measures (management, etc,..), and the species that are found in those sites and a measure of how the environmental measures effect species composition....I am wondering if there is a way to also add species data so that there is some measure, not only of what species are characteristic of a site and its environmental measures, but to add several traits of those species (Var1, var2, var3). In essence to measure what traits are characteristic of the species that inhabit a given site.

Comment: What does `View()` function do, and what do you mean by fitting `View(something)`?

Comment: The way you created `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, these variables are related to species rather than SUs. So you should fit them to species scores instead of sampling unit scores (site scores). You *can* do this, of course. Here "can" means that it is technically possible (and even very easy), but I do not endorse this as a sound practice. After all, the species scores are secondary and the actual NMDS solution only has SU scores.

Comment: View just views the datasheet. I just put in the code so its easy to see the form of the data sheet.

Comment: yes exactly. I don't want to fit spec.env to site scores. site scores are in dune.env.

Answer (score 1):

Use argument `display`  in `envfit` to select the kind of scores you want to use. With your example, that would be:

```
specfit <- envfit(ord ~ var1 + var2 + var3, dune.spec, display="sp")
plot(specfit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use ordisurf() which models a general additive model in the form of: 'environmental variable'~nmds1+nmds2, it will plot a model in three dimensional space which can be useful to show an environmental variable across multivariate space. If you want to compare the variance between dune and dune.env then I suggest using a co-inertia